# Is it possible to change j2me application to android application?

Tags: android, java-me, lwuit

I developed j2me based application with LWUIT framework.
Is it possible to change the this application to android based application?
Or can i need to create new project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used [LWUIT](http://www.pader-sync.com/lwuit-for-blackberry-and-android.html) for this purpose. They created LWUITActivity class for android platform.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to take parts of your code across as android is still java but I would say that you're going to have to rewrite most of it and probably all of the code for the user interface. J2ME and Android are designed very differently

Comment: OK. but my project is little bit big. give me any solution for this. I developed UI with LWUIT and i used some native API in j2me. like PIM..

Comment: There is an android port of LWUIT but I can't imagine that it will be as easy as just taking the code across.

Answer (score 1):

You have to completely rewrite your code from J2ME to Android. I was looking for a kind of translator from J2ME->Android but find nothing. In the end I'm now converting my J2ME codes into Android. Android possibilities are much more powerful than cut-down API's of J2ME. So you'll found that your new code will be nicer than elder J2ME code.

Though if you're going just launch J2ME jar/jad in Android - it's in theory possible, since KVM is just a subset of ordinary JVM (in case of Android Dalvik VM). There're some efforts to translate KVM byte-code into Dalvik's byte-codes. For instance [look here](http://www.netmite.com/android/srv/1.6/getapk.php)